# Cannot delete 'me' permission

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-realtime-api, google-drive-api

I'm using Google API in PHP. If I share a document with the API from another account I cannot remove, delete, or trash the shared file with the API.

```
$g_sd = $this->g_client->getGoogleServiceDrive();

$g_doc = $g_sd->files->get($doc_id);

if($g_doc->sharedWithMeDate)
{
    $g_sd->permissions->delete($g_doc->id, 'me');
}
```

So in this case, the `$doc_id` is coming from a document that I have shared from another account with the API email.

I keep getting this error:

```
Error calling DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1gQNCLBLY_rMFzH45Dnpo-Le-L-WGoDEz-Tv7JNLWy60/permissions/me: (404) Permission not found: me
```

The permission exists because I can dump the permission object when I do this:

```
$permission = $g_sd->permissions->get($g_doc->id, 'me');
print_r($permission, true);
```

Here is the output:

```
Google_Service_Drive_Permission Object
(
    [additionalRoles] => 
    [authKey] => 
    [domain] => 
    [emailAddress] => 
    [etag] => "AkM7BvofPa_Jxo7Kxgh76A7i7OE/lJV6AGH_OKQMZemIyVS-vZkisU0"
    [id] => me
    [kind] => drive#permission
    [name] => 
    [photoLink] => 
    [role] => writer
    [selfLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1gQNCLBLY_rMFzH45Dnpo-Le-L-WGoDEz-Tv7JNLWy60/permissions/me
    [type] => user
    [value] => 
    [withLink] => 
    [collection_key:protected] => items
    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [processed:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I have also tried:

```
$g_sd->files->trash($g_doc->id);
```

And:

```
$g_sd->files->delete($g_doc->id);
```

I just got this error:

```
Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1gQNCLBLY_rMFzH45Dnpo-Le-L-WGoDEz-Tv7JNLWy60/trash: (403) Insufficient permissions for this file
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the owner of a file can trash or delete it.  If you try to do this with a user with view or edit access, you will get a permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself by a lot of trial and error.

You have to get the permissionId of the self initialized Google Drive Service. You can get this information from the about attribute using the get() method. I'm guessing this is some kind of default global account permissionId. So in this case, this is the permissionId of the API account itself.

`$g_sd->permissions->delete($g_doc->id, $g_sd->about->get()->permissionId);`

I hope this makes sense and saved someone else hours of frustration. This information is NOT on the web at all. Trust me, I've looked.